# Cannot uninstall / repair / install Node.JS to my system

Tags: node.js

I installed node.js to work on a discord bot with VSCode but it didn't work.

I reinstalled it but ticked the 'install chocolatey' box this time, halfway through the installation I got 3 trojan alerts from my AV, and cancelled the installation.

Since then, I have been unable to uninstall, repair or reinstall Node.JS, through the Windows 10 uninstall function or from the Node.JS .msi file.

Each time I try, I get the same error message:
"The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if you are running Windows in safe mode, or if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed."

I've removed all instances of Node.JS from my program files and %appdata%, I've ensure the Installer Service is running, and yet the Node.JS application still shows in the Uninstall Tool and when I try to uninstall / modify / reinstall, it shows the same error, and seems to think it's still installed on my system! Not even Node.JS commands work in my CMD!

I've got no idea how to fix this, and I don't want to use glitch anymore to write my bot, so please help- or it seem's I'll have to factory reset my PC and hope that resolves the issue.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Godspeed.

EDIT: I tried installing a newer version hoping it would overwrite old Node.JS files. Didn't work. Issue still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Do these:

- Open command prompt as Administrator and run `/sfc scannow`. It will scan and replace corrupted files.
- Restart your PC when the scan is done.